# Brockett integrator and constant input values

Tags: control-theory

I have been trying to reach origin $(0, 0, 0)$ with the so-called Brockett integrator.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot x \\
\dot y \\
\dot z
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
u \\
v \\
yu - xv
\end{bmatrix} \stackrel{t \in [t_k, t_k+T_k]}{\Longrightarrow} \begin{bmatrix} x_{k+1} \\ y_{k+1} \\ z_{k+1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_k + T_k u_k \\ y_k + T_k v_k \\ z_k + T_k (y_k u_k - x_k v_k) \end{bmatrix}
$$

Inbetween steps:

$$\begin{cases} \dot{x} = u_k \\ \dot{y} = v_k \end{cases} \Longrightarrow \begin{cases} x(t) = x_k + (t - t_k) u_k \\ y(t) = y_k + (t - t_k) v_k \end{cases}$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\dot{z} & = (y_k + (t - t_k) v_k) \, u_k - (x_k + (t - t_k) u_k) v_k \\
& = (y_k \, u_k + (t - t_k) v_k \, u_k)  - (x_k \, v_k + (t - t_k) u_k \, v_k) \\
& = y_k \, u_k - x_k \, v_k
\end{aligned}
$$
$$\therefore z(t) = z_k + (t-t_k) (y_k \, u_k - x_k \, v_k)$$

For that, I try to work backwards, i.e. $0 = (x_{k+1}, y_{k+1}, z_{k+1})$. From that, we find $(u_k, v_k)$ equal to $-\frac{1}{T} (x_k, y_k)$, which leads to $z_k = 0$. We can only go to the origin from an initial state $(x, y, 0)$.

So, how can we steer to origin from arbitrary point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ passing through to $(x, y, 0)$ with at least two intervals constant input values $(u_k, v_k)$?

Comment: Isn't it $yu-x\color{red}{v}$ in the third line of the RHS vector of the first relationship ?

Comment: You are correct, sir. Thanks!

Comment: That isn't an exact discretization (the forward Euler is approximate...) and will likely lead you astray if you want to answer the question for the original continuous time system. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza I added some in-between steps to show, that the solution I present is indeed the correct flow trajectory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty much there. You recognize that it is easy to drive the system to the origin from initial states where $z = 0.$ Your first goal is then to find a control action that drives the system to that plane. If $x_0 \neq 0$ or $y_0 \neq 0$, then the solution is clear. For instance, if $x_0 \neq 0$ set

$$u_0 = 0,\quad v_0 = \frac{z_0}{T_k\,x_0}$$

and you are assured that $z_1 = 0$. Clearly, we need to special case when $x_0 = y_0 = 0$, but that only requires one additional action prior to this which involves making *at least one of these states* non-zero. Just choose any non-zero action for $u$ and/or $v$. It is this exception that makes it *at least two* intervals of constant control action.

After this sample period, you can then do what you already suggested which is set

$$u_1 = -\frac{x_1}{T_1},\quad v_1 = -\frac{y_1}{T_1}.$$

Together that makes two intervals of control action with the exceptional case of three when the initial state is on the vertical axis $x_0 = y_0 = 0.$ If you are looking for a proof for why it must be at least two, you should search for a contradiction assuming this initial condition.

Comment: Surprise, this was my other account. Nice to read your answer, Rollen. :-P